# Получение элемента с другого сайта

Tags: javascript, jquery

В `div` сайта `example1.ru` нужно вставить `div` с сайта `example2.ru`.

Написал такой код, но он почему-то не работает.
В чем может быть проблема?

```html
<div id="vip_view_div_cross"></div>
```

```js
$("#vip_view_div_cross").load("example2.ru #vip_view_div");
```

Comment: это же парсинг , как правило на php , а на ajax делается лишь только подгрузка

Comment: В запрете на кроссдоменный доступ без явного разрешения от второго сайта.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```js
getElement('http://ru.stackoverflow.com', '#nav-questions', function(element) {
    console.log(element);
});

getElement('http://ru.stackoverflow.com', '.question-hyperlink', function(element) {
    console.log(element.innerHTML);
});

function getElement(url, selector, c) {
    request(new XMLHttpRequest());

    function request(xhr) {
        xhr.open('GET', 'https://crossorigin.me/' + url, true);
        xhr.send();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(xhr.readyState == 4) {
                if(xhr.status == 200) {
                    html = document.createElement('div');
                    html.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                    c(html.querySelector(selector));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

<sub>jquery</sub>

```js
$('#q').load('https://crossorigin.me/http://ru.stackoverflow.com #nav-questions');
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<div id='q'></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. вы мне очень помогли!

Comment: Надеюсь следующий вопрос не будет «А как мне залогиниться на example2.com»…

Comment: нет, на самом деле я понял, что такой путь не совсем правильный (не всегда стабильно всё работать будет в моём случае), но сам ответ мне помог разобраться в теме.

Comment: Уже не работает, видимо `crossorigin.me` прикрыли)

Comment: Запрос из постороннего источника заблокирован: Политика одного источника запрещает чтение удаленного ресурса на https://crossorigin.me/http://ru.stackoverflow.com. (Причина: отсутствует заголовок CORS «Access-Control-Allow-Origin»).
2
Запрос из постороннего источника заблокирован: Политика одного источника запрещает чтение удаленного ресурса на https://crossorigin.me/http://ru.stackoverflow.com. (Причина: не удалось выполнить запрос CORS).
2

Answer (score 3):

Селал в виде букмарклета  -  вычисление килограмма золота в рублях
спасибо #Mr.Black

```
javascript:getElement('https://www.cbr.ru/', '#widget_metal', function(element) { alert(parseFloat(element.getElementsByClassName('nowrap')[2].innerHTML.replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/,/,'.'))*1000 + "%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9"); }); function getElement(url, selector, c) { request(new XMLHttpRequest()); function request(xhr) { xhr.open('GET', 'https://crossorigin.me/' + url, true); xhr.send(); xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { if(xhr.readyState == 4) { if(xhr.status == 200) { html = document.createElement('div'); html.innerHTML = xhr.responseText; c(html.querySelector(selector)); } } } } };
```