# Как получить доступ к своему словарю Lingualeo через скрипт JS?

Tags: javascript, доступ

Добрый день!

Ищу способ копирования слов из словаря Lingualeo на свой локальный диск. В скрипте буду указывать свой логин и пароль.

**Искал ответ и наткнулся на интересное решение:**
    https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/538112/254132

Однако, как я понял, в решении не предусматривается наличие профиля (с доступом через логин и пароль).

*Это мой 1-й вопрос. Если что-то неточно - я с удовольствием дополню.*

Comment: получается вы не знаете как через скрипт зайти под логином и паролем?

Comment: да, чтобы можно было получить доступ к словам.